# How do I generate an integer list that can be used as args to my PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, parameters

I have a fully working PS script which expects a set of integers which are all object numbers to be copied from a library onto a flash drive.  This command looks something like:

extract e: 1234 1235 1236

and it works fine - it just loops over the $args[1..n] and copies the object related files to flash drive (e: in the example).

Quite often there is a large sequential set of object numbers (usually 6 digit ones) and typing them in is a chore. So, when I discovered the n..n trick I thought I would use that like this (to copy object 100-120):

$objList = 100..120 -join " "
and then

extract e: $objList

But no, my script seems to see $objList as a single string not a space separated list and I get:

```
DBCheckItemExists : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'ItemID'. Cannot convert
value "100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120" to type
"System.Int64". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
```

So clearly PS doesn't think this is convertible to a set of integer args

If I write out the content of $objList to the screen I get the expected:

```
100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120
```

and if I then cut and paste that onto an extract command line then it works. So obviously this is some kind of datatype issue, so I tried prefixing the variable and the range with @ symbol to make them be strings - but no, I just got error messages.

There has to be something obvious I am misssing here - but I am at a loss!  Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With `-join " "` you convert the list to a string. One alternative is to just parse the list in your function, e.g.:

```
function foo {
  for ($i=0; $i -lt $args.length; $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j -lt $args[$i].length; $j++) {
      $args[$i][$j];
    }
  }
}
```

Test it with:

```
foo 100 (103..105) 99 (323..330)
```

Output:

```
100
103
104
105
99
323
324
325
326
327
328
329
330
```

It might be an idea to convert your function to use a `process` block to handle input, see for example [this post](https://4sysops.com/archives/understanding-powershell-begin-process-and-end-blocks/).